# How do I make page navigation in Nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, frontend, nuxt.js

There is such an [Api](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments)  with comments. How to properly paginate and view each comment separately? Get the whole object and use slice () to paginate, or is there some method to get comments in chunks for one page? And the same moment is incomprehensible for the output of one comment.

Comment: Hi, what did you tried so far?

Comment: Hi. Only slice()

Comment: What? Please make some extra effort here. SO is not a coding service.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Nuxt uses file-based navigation system so you don't have to do any effort for routing. And to view each comment on a separate page you can just use the param page that starts with `_`.